# Is it possible to split the string and take out only a single character in Cloudformation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my Cloudformation template I want to take only the first character of a string!
For e.g.

I have the following parameter

```
EnvType: 
 Default: Dev
```

And what I want to do is in my Tags,

```
Name: !Sub '${AWS::Region}${AWS::AccountID}${EnvType}'
```

In this I do not want Dev to appear in the name, I only want the first character of Dev. Which is D!
Is it possible to do with split or any other functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intrinsic functions in Cloudformation to perform the transformation/join/split on the strings.

In this case, you can try using `split` like below:

```
!Select [0, !Split ["", !Sub ${EnvType}]]
```

And if you want to join it with other values in the "Name", something like this will work:

```
Name: !Join
   - ''
   - - !Sub '${AWS::Region}${AWS::AccountID}
     - !Select [0, !Split ["", !Sub ${EnvType}]]
```

You can refer [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) documentation for more details

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can't use [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) for empty delimiter.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Type: String
    Default: "Dev"
Resources:
  MySNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Sub 'myrepcious'
          - !Select [0, !Split ["", !Ref EnvType]]
```

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: every Fn::Split object requires a non-empty delimiter.

so you are left with writing a  custom macro for doing this.

[custom macros published by awslambda](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions)

[How and Why to Use CloudFormation Macros](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/cloudformation-macros/)

[How to install and use the Boto3 macro in your AWS account](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Boto3)

[Using AWS CloudFormation macros to perform custom processing on templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)